# Transfer numbers in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created two tables. The first table I name it **atable** and the second table I name it **second** . On the atable I have **3x3(3 columns x 3 rows)** and on the second I have **1x9**. I want to fill in the first table with numbers, I have created the ***begin()***  function so I will fill the table with random items,using a button named **Start**.Next, I have created a function named  **check()**, it clicks on the first table(atable). Now, what I want to do is ,when I click on the table(atable)  I want each of my clicking to transfer the number into the other table(named :second ).I have created the table second but I didn't find how to send the clicks from one table into the other table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>            
            var timerid;
            var secs = 30;
            var randomNumber;
            var mclics = 0;
            var mcorrect = 0;   
        

    
            function begin() {
                            randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
                            
                var atable = document.getElementById("atable");
                for (i = 0; i < atable.rows.length; i++) {
                    for(j = 0; j < atable.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                        var a = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
                        atable.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = a;
                    }
                }
                
            }

            
            function check(trgt){
            if(trgt.tagName=="TD"){
                mclics++                            
                trgt.onclick=false;                 //for not happen again click//
            if((trgt.innerHTML%randomNumber)==0){
                mcorrect++                          //right clicks
                trgt.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }   
            else{
                trgt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            }
            
            }
            
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="begin()"  style="width: 30%"><br>
        <p id="anumber"></p>
        <table id="atable" border="1" onclick="check(event.target)">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"> </td>
                <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 260px; height: 39px;">
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 332px; height: 46px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 260px; height: 46px;">
            </tr>
            <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 172px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 332px; height: 172px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 260px; height: 172px;"> </tr>
                
        </table>   

        <p >Remaining time: </p>
        <p id="atimer"></p> 

<table id="second" border="1" >
            <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"> </td> </tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
                
            <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td></tr>
            <tr>    <td style="width: 332px; height: 46px;"></td></tr>
                
            <tr><td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
                
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first table I added "EventListener". When you click on a number field, the function is called function `getNumbers()` which adds the number to the other table. So that one digit cannot be added more than once. When you click on a field with a number, "EventListener" is automatically removed. The function `getNumbers()` loop the fields in the second table and fills in the next blank field.

*I have marked the new things in your code with a comments `// NEW CODE LINE`*

**Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var timerid;
        var secs = 30;
        var randomNumber;
        var mclics = 0;
        var mcorrect = 0;



        function begin() {
            randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

            var atable = document.getElementById("atable");
            for (i = 0; i < atable.rows.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < atable.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
                    atable.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = a;

                    // NEW CODE LINE
                    atable.rows[i].cells[j].addEventListener("click", function () {
                        getNumbers(this.innerText);
                        this.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee);
                    });
                    // END NEW CODE LINE
                }
            }

        }

        function check(trgt) {
            if (trgt.tagName == "TD") {
                mclics++
                trgt.onclick = false;                 //for not happen again click//
                if ((trgt.innerHTML % randomNumber) == 0) {
                    mcorrect++                          //right clicks
                    trgt.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }
                else {
                    trgt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }

        }

        // NEW CODE LINE
        function getNumbers(x) {
            var target = document.getElementById('second').getElementsByTagName('td');
            for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
                if (target[i].innerText.length === 0) {
                    target[i].innerText = x;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // END NEW CODE LINE

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="begin()" style="width: 30%"><br>
    <p id="anumber"></p>
    <table id="atable" border="1" onclick="check(event.target)">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"> </td>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 260px; height: 39px;">

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 46px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 260px; height: 46px;">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 172px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 172px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 260px; height: 172px;">
        </tr>

    </table>

    <p>Remaining time: </p>
    <p id="atimer"></p>

    <table id="second" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 46px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Version 2:**

Does not start before pressing the "Start" button. Cleans the contents of both tables when the "Start" button is pressed again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var timerid;
        var secs = 30;
        var randomNumber;
        // var mclics = 0;
        var mcorrect = 0;

        function begin() {

            // NEW CODE LINE
            mcorrect = 0;

            var tableA = document.getElementById('atable').getElementsByTagName('td');
            for (var i = 0; i < tableA.length; i++) {
                tableA[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
                tableA[i].removeEventListener("click", getClick);
            }

            var tableB = document.getElementById('second').getElementsByTagName('td');
            for (var i = 0; i < tableB.length; i++) {
                tableB[i].innerText = '';
            }
            // END NEW CODE LINE

            randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

            var atable = document.getElementById("atable");
            for (i = 0; i < atable.rows.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < atable.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
                    atable.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = a;

                    // NEW CODE LINE
                    atable.rows[i].cells[j].addEventListener("click", getClick);
                    // END NEW CODE LINE
                }
            }

        }

        // function check(trgt) {
        //     if (trgt.tagName == "TD") {
        //         mclics++
        //         trgt.onclick = false;                 //for not happen again click//
        //         if ((trgt.innerHTML % randomNumber) == 0) {
        //             mcorrect++                          //right clicks
        //             trgt.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        //         }
        //         else {
        //             trgt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        //         }
        //     }
        // }

        // NEW CODE LINE
        function getClick() {
            getNumbers(this.innerText, this);
            this.removeEventListener("click", getClick);
        }

        function getNumbers(x, y) {

            if ((y.innerHTML % randomNumber) == 0) {
                mcorrect++                          //right clicks
                y.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
            else {
                y.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }

            var target = document.getElementById('second').getElementsByTagName('td');
            for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
                if (target[i].innerText.length === 0) {
                    target[i].innerText = x;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // END NEW CODE LINE

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="begin()" style="width: 30%">
    <br>

    <p id="anumber"></p>
    <table id="atable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"> </td>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 260px; height: 39px;">

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 46px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 260px; height: 46px;">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 172px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 172px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 260px; height: 172px;">
        </tr>

    </table>

    <p>Remaining time: </p>
    <p id="atimer"></p>

    <table id="second" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 46px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 332px; height: 39px;"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So either I did this backward or this is how you wanted it. If you meant like, a long (height) table then this is what you want. If you want a wide table, just switch the `secondTable.rows[mclics].cells[0].innerHTML = trgt.innerHTML` to `secondTable.rows[0].cells[mclics].innerHTML = trgt.innerHTML` and reformat the table to only have one row. This code simply takes the innerHTML of the cell that you click and add it to the next table's next spot. There is no check though, so it will error once you fill-up the second table. Good luck!

```
function check(trgt) {
    var secondTable = document.getElementById("second");
    if (trgt.tagName == "TD") {
        secondTable.rows[mclics].cells[0].innerHTML = trgt.innerHTML
        mclics++

        trgt.onclick = false; //for not happen again click//
        if ((trgt.innerHTML % randomNumber) == 0) {
            mcorrect++ //right clicks
            trgt.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else {
            trgt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Table (second):

````html
          <table id="second" style="border: 1;" >
                <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 39px;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 46px;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 292px; height: 172px;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 332px; height: 172px;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="width: 260px; height: 172px;"></td></tr>
            </table>```
````